# Highcharts - Drilldown with setSize causes chart corruption

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to be able to resize my chart when I drill down through data, because for instance, my top level might only have say, a series of 3, where my drilldown might be a series of 10 or vice versa. However, I am having an issue with this.

Using this fiddle I am able to reproduce the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/

```
  type: 'bar',
  events: {
            drilldown: function(e) {
           this.setSize( this.chartWidth, ( e.seriesOptions.data.length * 50 ) + 150 );

            },
            drillup: function(e) {
           this.setSize( this.chartWidth, ( e.seriesOptions.data.length * 50 ) + 150 );
        }
     }                 
  },
```

Notice: If you drill down to Internet Explorer, the bottom will say "Proprietary or Undetectable", this is left over from the top level "Brands" chart.

If I remove the the this.setSize stuff, the chart will work correctly.

Here is my chart with the above changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/7oatr7xe/

Image of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igao7.png

Comment: I think this is caused by redrawing twice the chart, so before original redraw applies, you call second one. I would set redraw to false, see: http://jsfiddle.net/7oatr7xe/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea if this is a bug, but it seems you can solve it if you call setSize with a timeout (even 1ms seems to work)

```
        drilldown: function(e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                    this.setSize( this.chartWidth, ( e.seriesOptions.data.length * 50 ) + 150 );
            }, 1);
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7oatr7xe/1/

Comment: That seems to work but I hate having to add timers like this.

Comment: I hate those timer too :/
 You could post this issue in the highcharts forum, if it's a bug I'm sure the want to know about it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in drillDown you redraw chart and in setSize you try to do it the same. The solution is set flag redraw (in setSize) as false.

```
            drilldown: function(e) {
                this.setSize( this.chartWidth, ( e.seriesOptions.data.length * 50 ) + 150,false );

            },
            drillup: function(e) {
                this.setSize( this.chartWidth, ( e.seriesOptions.data.length * 50 ) + 150,false );
            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7oatr7xe/3/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work for that fiddle.  However, my real work has an extra level of drill down and somehow the problem persists there.  I'll see if I can add a drilldown level to reproduce what I'm seeing.